# jQuery - Parse Json then Display Data

Tags: json, jquery

I'm having a problem parsing valid Json from a Twitter List then displaying the list on the page.

Here is my code;

```
var url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/aplusk/lists/5676047/statuses.json&callback=?";

$.getJSON(url, function(data) { 
var results = '';

$(data.results).each(function() {
results += "<p class='tweet_result' id='tweet" + this.id_str + "'><a href='http://twitter.com/" + this.user.screen_name + "' title='' class='tweet_user'></p>";
});

$(results).prependTo("#twitter_results");
});
```

If you put the url in to [www.jslint.com](http://www.jsonlint.com/) you can view the structure of the json

I'm new to json so I could be doing something stupid here.

Thanks in advance for your help and advice.

Comment: What is the problem you're having?

Comment: There are no jQuery errors but nothing is displaying when I append the results to a div. I'm sure I'm not correctly parsing the file or referring to the correct nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL has to be:

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/aplusk/lists/5676047/statuses.json?callback=?
```

(Note the question mark instead of the ampersand)

Also see the returned object, it does'nt have a member "results", it's a native javascript-array.

You'll have to iterate over data itself:

```
$(data).each(function(i,item)
```

where you can access the properties inside via

```
item.someProperty
```

Comment: Oh mannn... well i did say it was something studpid. Many thanks for the help.